# What can I do to improve my Fibonacci number generator?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I'm solving this problem:

> ```
> G(n) is defined as
>
> G(n) = G(n-1) + f(4n-1) , for n > 0
>
> and G(0) = 0
>
> f(i) is ith Fibonacci number. Given n you need to evaluate G(n)
> ```
>
> modulo 1000000007.
>
> ```
> Input
>
> First line contains number of test cases t (t<40000). Each of the next t
> ```
>
> lines contain an integer n ( 0 <= n <
>   2^51).
>
> ```
> Output
>
> For each test case print G(n) modulo 1000000007.
>
> Example
>
> Input:
> 2
> 2
> 4
>
>
>
> Output:
>
>
> 15
> 714
> ```

This is the code I've written:

```
typedef long long type;
#define check 1000000007
type x;
type y;

type f(type n)
{
    return(ceil((pow(1.618,n) - pow(-0.618,n))/((sqrt(5)*1.0))));
}
type val(type n)
{
    if(n==0)
    return 0;
    else 
    return (val(n-1)+f(4*n-1));
}
int main()
{
    cin>>x;
    while(x--)
    {
       cin>>y;
       cout<<val(y)%check<<endl;
       }
    //getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Can you suggest any improvements?

Comment: Start with meaningful names. Instead of `type`, call it what it really represents: `number` or something. Instead of `check`, I'd probably use `divisor` or something.

Comment: What is the judge's output? Wrong Answer, Time Limit Exceeded?

Comment: please suggest some optimizations in this code..

Comment: compiler error..but its running on my machine

Comment: @prp you are missing some #imports

Comment: There is also an O(log(n)) algorithm for Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: I sincerely think this method is unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes such problems can be tackled with mathematical tricks,
instead of brute force solutions.

The large value of `n` and modulo, in my opinion, are indications that
a clever solution exists. Of course figuring out the solution is the hard part.

(I'm not sure if this is ideal in your case, I'm only pointing you an alternative way)

For example, in the [Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1: Fundamental Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896834)
Knuth uses "generating functions", a clever way for constructing a closed form
for the Fn fibonacci number.

For more info read [Generating Functions (pdf)](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/fall05/ln11.pdf)

> Why should one care about the
>   generating function for a sequence?
>   There are several answers, but here is
>   one: if we can ﬁnd a generating
>   function for a sequence, then we can
>   often ﬁnd a closed form for the nth
>   coefﬁcient— which can be pretty
>   useful! For example, a closed form for
>   the coefﬁcient of x<sup>n</sup> in the
>   power series for x/(1−x−x<sup>2</sup>)
>   would be an explicit formula for the
>   nth Fibonacci number. [...]

Answer (score 1):

G(n) = G(n-1) + f(4n-1) = G(n-2) + f(4n-1) + f(4n-5) etc.

therefore

G(n) = f(4n-1) + f(4n-5) + f(4n-9) ... f(3)

f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) = 2f(n-2) + f(n-3) = 3f(n-3) + 2f(n-4) = 5f(n-4) + 3f(n-5)
f(n-5) = 3f(n-8) + 2f(n-9)
thus
f(n) = 5f(n-4) + 9f(n-8) + 6f(n-9)
= 5f(n-4) + 9f(n-8) + 18f(n-12) + 12f(n-13)

= 5f(n-4) + 9f(n-8) + 18f(n-12) + 36f(n-16) + 24f(n-17)

in any case it is clear the coefficients will double each time. Of course from the above we can define f(n-4) in terms of f(n-8) etc. Not sure where this will lead.

There is a series here and f(3)=2 and f(2) = 1 so at the end you will add the constant.

Practically though for your purpose you can calculate f(n) in a single pass without having to store more than 2 of them at this point and as you know the formula for G above, as you pass through calculating f(n) you can update G as appropriate summing the fibonnaci numbers when n is congruent to 3 mod 4 at each point.

You will not find the space to save a table with such a huge number (2 to the power of 51) not even to disk, though it is really the sums you need to store in a table (f(3), f(3)+f(7), f(3)+f(7)+f(11) etc.) if you were going to save anything.

Answer (score 0):

So f() is the fibonacci function? I would suggest that you use the regular recursive algorithm. But you can improve performance significantly by adding a cache, as calls to f(i) for smaller values of i will be repeated very often.

You can do that by using a static local array of integers. If the element is 0 it's a miss so you calculate the value and store it in the array.

That way you avoid using floating point operations and you won't fill up the stack.

Comment: Even adding a cache, computing every fibonacci number for every i from 1 to 4*(2^51)-1 would take forever -- even at 1 ns per number it would take over 3 months and good luck computing them even that fast. Assuming you even have the memory to store all the values

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to get value of `G(n)` is to compute it like this:

```
type val(type n, std::vector<type> &fib)
{
  type ret = 0, s = min(type(fib.size()), n);
  for(type i=0; i < s; ++i)
      ret += fib[i];

  if(n > fib.size()){    
    fib.reserve(n);
    int tmp;
    for(type i = fib.size(); i < n; ++i){
      tmp = f(4*i+3);
      fib.push_back(tmp);
      ret += tmp;
    }

  }
  return ret;
}
```

(For whole code check http://www.ideone.com/jorMy)

Avoid recursion everywhere it's possible and this way it won't compute everytime Fibonacci function.

**Edit:** I've spent much time to find that (my math is little rusty), but you can also write val like this:

```
numtype val(numtype n) {
  return ceil(2.218*pow(6.8541,n-1) - 0.018*pow(0.145898,n-1) - 0.2);
}
```

(code on http://www.ideone.com/H1SYz)

This is closed form of your sum. If you want to find it by yourself (it's homework after all) follow Nick D answer.

Comment: I don't see this returning anytime soon for n = 2^51. Well, other than dying after running out of heap space.

Comment: Yeah, so you can ommit vector if you want to count this for such a big numbers. It was only added to make computing faster. And if you don't know how to remove it, here's the code: http://www.ideone.com/BMBHb